# Waterproof tile trim for kitchen - how to do the floor/wall

Tags: kitchens, tile, waterproofing

so I am working through a kitchen renovation, starting with the floor. The kitchen is about 14'x11', plus a small walk-in pantry.

At this point, I am still doing the existing floor removal and sub-floor repair, and I expect it will be 2-3 weekends before I am ready to lay ceramic tile, so I am carefully reviewing the tile plan, which is as-follows:

- Sub-floor should be acceptable for ceramic tile: joists are 2x12", 16" on center, existing sub-floor is 5/8" plywood; I am replacing the 5/8" under the sink area and stove area and then adding 3/4" tongue-and-groove treated plywood on top
- Once the sub-floor is in; the plan is to check the level with a laser leveler and adjust as-needed; I'm prepared to do a self-leveling pour if I have to
- planning to use Schluter Ditra underlayment with recommended mortars for the floor coverage
- floor trim will be matching tile (the floor is hexagons, and I got matching rectangles that will be nice trim when cut into thirds)
- flooring and trim will go under and behind the cabinets with the aim of achieving a floor that can withstand some spilled water
- To that end, Kerdi-band looks like the right product to seal the membrane seams and around the wall-floor transitions
- so, the plan to install the trim is again get the Schluter products and use Kerdi membrane just behind the trim, except behind the sink where I plan to replace the drywall with Kerdi board
- once all the membranes and tapes are on, I would leave a 1/8" expansion gap between the tile and the wall, and then another 1/8" gap between the trim and the floor tile, filling the perimeter gaps with caulk rather than grout

That is how the plan works in my head; here are the questions:

- I've watched a lot of YouTube videos about how great the Schluter systems are; is this true or am I better off using backer board or competing products?
- For the perimeter gaps, the Schluter install manual and videos show various squishy corner products that (1) don't get a lot of explanation, and (2) don't seem to be necessary when there is a gap and caulk; do I need something there?  I get that flexible transition products are needed for large area coverage, but my kitchen is not large enough for those to be recommended.
- There seems to be a debate about caulk vs grout for the perimeter with a tile trim, and it looks like caulk is the safer way to go
- for managing a putative spill or leak, I imagine having 1/4" of water stay in the kitchen to be mopped up rather than flow through the floor or into another room, mainly by installing a 1/4" tall threshold in each of the two transitions to the rest of the house and a 1/4" tall floor register in the one vent hole, sealing both with caulk; is this sensible?
- am I missing anything major?

Thanks in advance for info and advice!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.